# CQL ALTER TABLE not working (add column + with properties)

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to run the following CQL command

```
ALTER TABLE keyspace_name_abc.table_name 
ADD (field1 text, field2 text)
WITH default_time_to_live = 15552000;
```

But it is not working, the error I'm getting is:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:NN mismatched input 'WITH' expecting EOF (...field1 text, field2 text [WITH] ...)
```

If I run that command separated, it works. Is there any limitation in CQL to combine multiple changes?

```
ALTER TABLE keyspace_name_abc.table_name 
ADD (field1 text, field2 text);

ALTER TABLE keyspace_name_abc.table_name 
WITH default_time_to_live = 15552000;
```

This way, the commands are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you'll be able to update the default TTL for a subset of columns, so you'll have to separate out those statements and run them like:

```
ALTER TABLE keyspace_name_abc.table_name ADD (field1 text, field2 text);
ALTER TABLE keyspace_name_abc.table_name WITH default_time_to_live = 15552000;
```

If you require some non-default TTL for a particular column, then you'll need to add that on the insert, for example:

```
INSERT INTO keyspace_name_abc.table_name (col1, col2, field1, field2) VALUES ('col1text', 'col2text', 'field1text', 'field2text') USING TTL 86400;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to set TTL at table level. Not for a particular column.

According to the documentation, the syntax is:

ALTER TABLE [keyspace_name.] table_name 
[ALTER column_name TYPE cql_type]
[ADD (column_definition_list)]
[DROP column_list | COMPACT STORAGE ]
[RENAME column_name TO column_name]
[WITH table_properties];

Comment: Good deal, in that case, you'll just need to update the default TTL outside of the ALTER statement that performs column level changes and it should succeed.  If it doesn't, let us know.

Comment: Can it be done in one single cql statement (add columns + update table TTL)? I have been trying like this and some other similar variations with no success: ALTER TABLE keyspace_name_abc.table_name 
ADD (field1 text, field2 text)
WITH default_time_to_live = 15552000;

Comment: Not when you are Altering columns, if you were changing table level settings you could perform those in a single statement.  For example, you could change the compaction strategy and update the default TTL in a single statement, but the Alter on the columns will need to be separated out.